# Error de fetch al enviar datos a php

Tags: php, javascript, fetch

Lo que sucede es que tengo este archivo javascript con un fetch al php mostrado mas adelante. Todo funciona hasta que intento agregar mas funciones al php

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    let datos = new FormData(formulario);

    console.log(datos.get('form-cuentaDe'));

    fetch("backend/main.php",{
        method:'POST',
        body: datos
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log('peticion fallida: ',err);
    })

    formulario.reset();

});
```

y el archivo php :

```
$cosa = $_POST['form-cuentaDe'];

if(!empty($cosa)){

    echo json_encode("Consulta exitosa");
}
```

El error es este:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Un ejemplo que causaria ese error seria incluir otro archivo php o crear una conexion sql :

```
$cosa = $_POST['form-cuentaDe'];

if(!empty($cosa)){

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cuentas");

    echo json_encode("Consulta exitosa");
}
```

Comment: tu archivo `.php` esta guardado con BOM o sin BOM?

Comment: Hay discusiones sobre si una simple cadena es un JSON válido: `echo json_encode("Consulta exitosa");` unos dicen que sí, otros que no. Para salir de dudas, ¿por qué no imprimes mejor un array?: `echo json_encode(array("txt"=>"Consulta exitosa"));`  Otra cosa que puedes intentar es renunciar (de momento) al json, traerlo como texto y ver lo que realmente está devolviendo el servidor, poniendo esto: `.then(res => res.text())` supongo que tienes clarísimo que el nuevo código que incluyes no debe sacar por pantalla nada, pero nada aparte de un JSON válido, ni siquiera un mini mini caracter, nada.

Comment: Okey, así lo hare entonces. Empecé hace un par de semanas a trabajar con desarrollo web, así que estoy un poco verde en algunos temas. Agradezco su ayuda.